# A DTD Element with EMPTY and PCDATA

Tags: xml, dtd

Can we declare an element in DTD like that :

```
<!ELEMENT name (EMPTY | (#PCDATA))>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to declare an element that is either empty or could contain character data (text) then no, you cannot declare an element like that.

See "contentspec" from the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#elemdecls):

> ```
> [46]      contentspec    ::=      'EMPTY' | 'ANY' | Mixed | children
> ```

You could declare an element like:

```
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA|EMPTY)*>
```

but that is saying `name` contains [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-Mixed) (both character data and child elements). In this case the possible child is an element named `EMPTY`.

You should declare the element like this:

```
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
```

This will allow `name` to contain character data or be empty.

For example, the following `name` elements would all be valid:

```
<name></name>
<name/>
<name>balimaco00</name>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification